What electronic component is this 6-pin mark "22ARKJ"
The package is SOT-23-6, it may be a switch power supply chip，but I can't find any information about it.


It's possibly a PWM controller made by Onsemi similar to the NCP125x series of devices. There is no datasheet available from Onsemi, but it might be a special part that's under NDA.
Here are my clues:
This Russian forum post about the same IC contains a pinout and two additional markings.

All known markings of this IC are (including this post):
22ARKJ
22ARZV
22AREE

If we now look at the NCP125x series of devices which is made by Onsemi, they all have the same two distinctive dots under the marking. Here an example of the NCP1253BSN65T1G from LCSC:

The markings follow the same pattern for all NCP125x I could find datasheets of:
NNxAYW with

NN = Device Code, examples: 25 (NCP1250), 53 (NCP1253), 5D (NCP12510)
x = Unexplained single character, only common character for all devices is A
A = Assembly Location, R in all pictures I could find
Y = Year
W = Work Week

Here is a screenshot of the NCP1250 datasheet as example:

The marking of the device in question 22ARxx follows this pattern pretty well. The 22 could mean that part number is something like NCP1222. However, the only hint for the existence of such a device is this patent which states:

The switching control circuit 15 may use NCP1222 PWM current-mode controller manufactured by On Semiconductor Corporation, and a compilation of its pin function description is tabulated in Table 1 for reference.
Table 1 is a compilation of pin function description of NCP1222 PWM current-mode controller manufactured by On Semiconductor Corporation.




No.
Pin Name
Function




1
Adj
Adjust the skipping peak current


2
FB
Set the peak current setpoint


3
CS
Current sense input


4
GND
The IC ground


5
DRV
Driving pulses


6
VCC
Supplies the IC


7
NC
No connection


8
HV
Generates the VCC from line



If we ignore the fact that this is a 8 pin device, it's pretty close to the pinout described in the Russian forum post. There is no information about a NCP1222 on the Onsemi homepage, however, so my guess is that it's under NDA and the only way to get further information is by contacting Onsemi directly.

,it might be a special part, i think so
